# Installation of YAF (https://tools.netsa.cert.org/yaf/download.html#)

Tags: recursion, installation, makefile, yaf

```
make[2]: *** [Makefile:684: yaf] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/prem/Downloads/yaf-2.8.4/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1054: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/prem/Downloads/yaf-2.8.4/src'
make: *** [Makefile:638: all-recursive] Error 1
```

I am getting this error while installing Yaf for traffic analysis.

Comment: These are not the real errors.  These are just make telling you that some command it invoked failed.  You have to look _before_ these messages to find the real errors.  Always when working with compilers or really tools of any kind you should pay attention to the _first_ errors generated by your tools and ignore the _last_ errors generated until the first ones are fixed: very often the last messages printed are side-effects of the first ones.

Comment: /bin/ld: ./.libs/libyaf.so: undefined reference to `fbSessionAddTemplateCallback'

Comment: Well, googling shows that seems to be related to the **fixbuf** library.  Looks like you'll have to debug this: maybe ask for help from the YAF folks.  This isn't a makefile issue as far as I can tell.